# Indesign RGB color space

Tags: adobe-indesign, color-spaces

Is there a way to set the colorspace to  sRGB in indesign?

I remember doing this in indesign cs3 years ago and i can't recall how to do this for cs5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your document is currently CMYK, this requires two steps:

1. Edit > Convert to Profile -- Set the RGB space to sRGB.
2. Edit > Transparency Blend Space > Document RGB.

For new documents, in CS5, choose "Web" for Intent, and the document will be created in RGB, with RGB swatches. Apply step 1 above if your default RGB setting is something other than sRGB.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the Transparency Blend Space was exactly what I wanted to do. My PDF looked correct, but my preview in InDesign looked super faded and it was hard to work with.

Comment: Transparency Blend Space is what I needed as well. For me everything looked OK in InDesign, but when I exported to PDF the colors were wrong. Changing the Transparency Blend Space fixed the PDF export!

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking to change your color palette to sRGB, you can do that by opening the Color palette window and on the drop down menu (upper right corner of the color palette window), change it to RGB.

If you already have a project going, I've only been able to swap things to sRGB by selecting everything and swapping it. But you have to be extremely careful in doing this as it can really mess up colors since you're essentially reducing the number of colors you're working with.