# What CSS blend mode will add white color without affecting black?

Tags: website-design, blend-modes

I would like to allow adjacent apps in my interface glow, overlaying each other with white, but the apps have a 0.25pt black border which I want to avoid diminishing. **Is there a blend mode which allows me to apply white to everything except for colors near black?**

[image]

By the way I'm working with CSS, so the blend modes available are limited:

> Not every blend mode has been translated from PhotoShop into CSS: as
>   of this writing, we have access to multiply, screen, overlay, darken,
>   lighten, color-dodge, color-burn, hard-light, soft-light, difference
>   and exclusion,

Comment: I don't follow your question. What do you mean by "Apply white to everything but black?" What part do you want to glow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can see an example of a blue box with a black stroke, on the right there's a white overlay. You can see that this does not effect the black.

[image: Box with overlay]

Therefore, overlay should be the effect you are looking for.

Hope this helps! :)

PS.for future reference on colours, [click here](http://www.worqx.com/color/color_systems.htm).

Comment: I tested this is InDesign, where Im working on the design mockup, but to no avail. I suspect the CYMK color space may be the problem.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, change to RGB (which is additive) and the overlay will then work :) also, CMYK is for print. You likely don't need this for your app!

Comment: Well Yep InDesign is for print so it uses CYMK but I find it useful for making fast web page mockups!

Comment: @ColorQuestor it is indeed for print but has many other uses, e.g online brochures, or even layout and mock ups like you're doing. There's a question [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/indesign-rgb-color-space) that states how to change the color space :)

Comment: Oh great, I didn't know about that, very neat thank you!