# Check colourspace in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, cmyk, rgb, color-spaces

So I've seen this answer on here:
[Indesign RGB color space](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/indesign-rgb-color-space)

But I'm wondering how do I tell what colourspace is currently applied to a document? I *think* the one I'm currently working in is set to CMYK, but I'd like to know how I can find out for sure.

If I visit `Edit > Convert to Profile` I see the following:

[image]

But this appears to show both RGB and CMYK, is any of this telling me what my document is currently set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, Indesign just does not assign a Color mode to a document (like Photoshop).
You can work with CMYK, RGB or even Lab swatches within the same document.
When it comes to Export, check out Output options to set up either CMYK or RGB profile.

However transparency effects will definitely be different if working in CMYK or RGB mode.
Go Edit > Transparency Blend Space > Document RGB or CMYK in order to set which mode should be used in case of transparency effects.

See example below. See how Transparency blend space affects colors, regardless of their color mode:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought I had to specify the colour mode somewhere too